# I'm having trouble with my bootstrap cdn in pycharm it's making my website look ugly lol

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, pycharm

```
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">
```

suggested fix by pycharm

```
<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="{% trans "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">
```

When I paste the top it gives me an error saying unexpected token then I do the recommended fix which It fixes the problem but when I test my index.html it shows nothing centered and my navbar doesn't go across the page like set it If anyone knows how to fix this issue please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fix by removing `integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"`

Comment: may be you remove "" from src

Comment: sorry `href`. If any error, add the console error log

Comment: So I check the console error log nothing but it tells me unexpected token so the http:// and 4.2.1 are giving me the error and on the http:// its the //

Comment: can you add what you try?

Comment: <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I suggest removing integrity. `<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I did that but main thing is the http:// on the // still and 4.2.1 there on error and  I tried the recomended one on pycharm which is this one<link crossorigin="anonymous" href="{% trans "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" %}"
          integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: I even downloaded bootstrap from the website and from pip install to see if it will make a difference but nope

Comment: You don't do this what I say. Please get help from a basic django tutorial.

Comment: think I'm running the right debug this is what it tells me

Comment: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'azvvU9xKluwHFJ0Cpgtf0CYzK7zgtOznnzxV4924X1w='. The resource has been blocked.

Comment: why you not remove integrity from <link> tag

Comment: when I delete it doesn't say anything but still gives me the token error

Comment: where you add your bootstrap?

Comment: {% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PollMe | Home</title>
    <link crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    {% block custom_css %}{% endblock %}
</head>

Comment: what {% load i18n%} I do not remember typing that in

Comment: you can find the link useful https://github.com/shafikshaon/meal_hisab/blob/master/templates/base.html

Comment: ok so I got everything running again but is my cdn not working like it use to

Comment: Hey Shafikur thanks I figured it out why my cdn wasn't working it had to do with pycharm language injection but the link you provided help me a lot on other stuff

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use bootstrap after creating your website... so better dont do it... else .. you need to rework on your custom css that  you have created for your website... change class names .. and try to use older version.. like bootstrap 3 or any....

Comment: ok I'll try it worked fine before the new year and I know pycharm did an update on the first of the month.

Comment: my custom css is not working I'm using django language it's telling that I need to put () around my custom css name

Comment: {% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block custom_css %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/styles' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}